# Contain mp4 video inside bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, video

I want to have a video on my website. But the video is not the same height as the pictures and i need this fixed. How can i make sure the video covers the entire column and is the same height as the other two columns at all times

Currently this is my code:

```
<div class="container" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 fullscreen-bg">
            <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
            <source src="video/kerntrekken.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="padding: 0;">
                <img src="img/Kluizen.jpg" width="100%" height="354">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="padding: 0;">
                <img src="img/Kluizen.jpg" width="100%" height="354">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my css:

```
.fullscreen-bg {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
  background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[https://i.gyazo.com/8210a9c6a5e0aa01225526fa70987b65.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJIgf.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Video tag** can take width and height as 100%

```html
<video width="100%" height="100%" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can't set the height of the video object. However, there is a simple CSS hack known as 
`object-fit`

You will may need to set the height of all the blocks and the video in the row, for example:

```
.col-md-4 img { height: 200px; } 
.col-md-4 video {
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: fill;
}
```

Failing that, just using the following may suffice:

```
.col-md-4 video {
    object-fit: fill;
}
```

Give them both a test!

For more information on how to use this, visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit